# Как вставить произвольную запись даты публикации при публикации поста?

Tags: wordpress, hook

Вопрос следующего характера:
Сайт на Wordpress. На сайте в кроне автоматически создаються посты и помещаються в черновики. Потом человек просматривает посты и публикует их. У поста изначально есть дата создания, но при публикации эта выставляется текущая дата публикации. Как собственно при публикации оставить старую дату или вставить е заново в новую опубликованную запись? Желательно хуками. Заранее спасибо.